# how to add values of form elements to an array every time I click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a html form with one select list of products and a text box for quantity and a submit button, I want to add values into array every time I click on submit button then I want to pass it to php through `$.post('testPhp.php', {selectedItems: array.Item, quantity: array.quantity}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **JSON.stringify( arr )**

```
var arr = ['mango', apple];
var serializedArr = JSON.stringify( arr );
```

then you can send it to server via ajax like simply you send other string values.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`.serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

It returns form element values in the following structure:

```
[
  {
    name: "a",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "b",
    value: "2"
  },
  {
    name: "c",
    value: "3"
  },
  {
    name: "d",
    value: "4"
  },
  {
    name: "e",
    value: "5"
  }
]
```

Or you can use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object

```
var formData = new FormData(form);
formData.append('selectedItems', array.Item);
formData.append('quantity', array.quantity);
```

Comment: how can i add it to $.post {selectedItem: item.array}